# Why is echo showing the command itself and not the command output

Tags: linux, bash, centos

Why is echo showing the command and not the output of the command once I start using it in a FOR I loop? For example this command works

```
root@linux1 tmp]# iscsiadm -m node |awk '{print $1}'
192.168.100.88:326
```

But not in a FOR I loop

```
[root@linux1 tmp]# for i in 'iscsiadm -m node | awk '{print $1}'';do echo $i;done
iscsiadm -m node | awk {print
}
```

I want the command to print the first field so then I can add other functionality to the For I loop. Thanks

EDIT -- Not sure why I got voted down on this question. Please advise.

Comment: I guess you got downvoted because your line has obvious errors that could easily be fixed by learning the rudimentary of shell scripting, maybe by asking yourself “how can I loop on the output of a process“ and finding an answer among all the sources available. If you're not satisfied with what you find, or you're not able to make it work, then (and only then) ask a question.

Comment: And among the answers you'd probably see: `while read -r i _; do echo "$i"; done < <(iscsiadm -m node)`, which is the correct answer.

Comment: Thank for your feedback. I can appreciate your point of view. I am professional in IT for 15 years and able to self teach. Therefore, I am teaching myself programming. However my brain is wired that way (yet) so I don't find these answers obvious. Once you know the answer it is obvious but in the beginning it is hard. Kind of snobby to have people shove it in your face if you ask me. But either way I am thankful for the people who did post helpful responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not executing the `iscsiadm` and `awk` commands, because you quoted it; that makes it a literal string. To substitute the output of a command back into the command line, use `$(...)`

```
for i in $(iscsiadm -m node |awk '{print $1}'); do
    echo $i
done
```